# Create a matrix in R studio that shows frequency of combinations

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, dplyr

I have a data frame with transaction numbers and the categories purchased within each transaction.
It looks something like this:

```r
trxn_num = c(1,2,3,3,3,4,5,5,6,7,7,7,7)
categories = c("pants","boots","boots","shirts","socks","pants","pants","socks", "shorts", "pants", "socks","boots","shirts")
df = cbind(trxn_num,categories)
```

I am trying to generate a matrix with both rownames and colnames to be the categories, and the value of each cell to represent the proportion of transactions that socks is paired with pants (for instance).
For clarity, the interaction of "socks", and "socks" should show 1.0 as 100% of the transactions that contain "socks" also contain "socks".
So the output would look like this matrix:

```r
cat.mat = matrix( nrow = 5, ncol = 5)
rownames(cat.mat) = unique(categories)
colnames(cat.mat) = unique(categories)
```

Except instead of NA's, there would be proportions.

I have tried using dplyr as follows:

```r
result = df %>%
         group_by(category,category) %>%
         summarise(trxns = length(unique(transaction_num)
```

However when I try that, R won't allow me to group by category twice.

Comment: You're making a `matrix` but you appear to be using [tag:dplyr] which works on `data.frame`, not `matrix`. If you truly are using frames, then please don't demonstrate code using `cbind` that creates an object that will clearly fail in your demo code. BTW, incomplete code, you're missing at least two close parens.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might perform the task you're trying to complete.

```
trxn_num = c(1,2,3,3,3,4,5,5,6,7,7,7,7)
categories = c("pants","boots","boots","shirts","socks","pants","pants","socks", "shorts", "pants", "socks","boots","shirts")
df = data.frame(trxn_num,categories)

mat = matrix(NA, nrow = length(unique(df$categories)), ncol = length(unique(df$categories)))
colnames(mat) <- unique(df$categories)
rownames(mat) <- unique(df$categories)

for(i in 1:length(unique(df$categories))){
  for (j in 1:length(unique(df$categories))){
    mat[i,j] = length(which(df$trxn_num[which(df$categories == unique(df$categories)[j])] %in% df$trxn_num[which(df$categories == unique(df$categories)[i])]))/length(which(df$categories == unique(df$categories)[i]))
  }
}
```

In order to get the number of transactions where category i (ex socks) and category j (ex pants) appear together, you can use the following code:

```
length(which(df$trxn_num[which(df$categories == unique(df$categories)[j])] %in% df$trxn_num[which(df$categories == unique(df$categories)[i])]))
```

And then to get a frequency, divide by the number of times category i appears:

```
length(which(df$categories == unique(df$categories)[i]))
```